# How can I add an "OR" value in php / ajax without repeating code?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

How can I add and "or" the correct way in this code if I wanted to add a second value other than "PENDING" without having to repeat all the code again? I want to add OR "VIP-PENDING" So it would say "PENDING" OR "VIP-PENDING". There are 3 spots it needs to be added in the code.

```
$result = " SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."bidsys_picklist WHERE  sport = ".$sport." AND pick_result!='PENDING' AND  ".$interval."  ORDER BY game_date DESC";
$newmeta = $wpdb->get_results($result);
```

2nd part of code on different line

```
else if($seasontype=="pending"){

    $result = " SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."bidsys_picklist WHERE  sport = ".$sport." AND pick_result='PENDING' ORDER BY game_date DESC";
$newmeta = $wpdb->get_results($result);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% clear about the problem, but have you tried using brackets? something like the following:

```
$result = " SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."bidsys_picklist WHERE  sport = ".$sport." AND (pick_result!='PENDING' OR pick_result!='VIP-PENDING') AND  ".$interval."  ORDER BY game_date DESC";
$newmeta = $wpdb->get_results($result);
```

Though is also is not clear in your definition if you want "=" (equaL) to PENDING or "!=" (distinct).